# String.Split returning incorrect array

Tags: vb.net

Attempting to correct an HTML table that is incorrectly formatted. I do not have control over the source, my application just loads the contents of a downloaded file as a regular text file. The file contents are a simple HTML table that is missing the closing `</tr>` elements. I'm attempting to split the contents on `<tr>` to get an array to which I can a `</tr>` to the end of the elements that need it. When I attempt to split the string using `fleContents.Split("<tr>").ToList` I'm getting a lot more elements in the resulting `List(Of String)` than there should be.

Here I a short little test code that shows the same behavior:

```
Dim testSource As String = "<table><tr><td>8172745</td><tr><td>8172745</td></table>"
Dim testArr As String() = testSource.Split("<tr>")

'Maybe try splitting on a variable because you can't use a string literal containging "<>" in the Split method
Dim seper as String = "<tr>"
testArr As String() = testSource.Split(seper)

'feed it a new string directly
testArr = testSource .Split(New String("<tr>"))
```

I would expect that `testArr` should contain 3 elements, as follows:

> 1. `"<table>"`
> 2. `"<td>8172745</td>"`
> 3. `"<td>8172745</td></table>"`

However, I am receiving the following array:

> 1. `""`
> 2. `"table>"`
> 3. `"tr>"`
> 4. `"td>8172745"`
> 5. `"/td>"`
> 6. `"tr>"`
> 7. `"td>8172954"`
> 8. `"/td>"`
> 9. `"/table>"`

Can someone please explain why the strings are being split the way they are and how I can go about getting the results I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using a different overload of the `Split` method than you're expecting. You want the method that takes a `String[]` and `StringSplitOptions` parameter:

```
Dim testSource As String = "<table><tr><td>8172745</td><tr><td>8172745</td></table>"
Dim delimeter As String() = { "<tr>" }
Dim testArr As String() = _
    testSource.Split(delimeter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

You can see it working at IDEOne:

http://ideone.com/pcw6aq

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Regex like that

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim testSource As String = "<table><tr><td>8172745</td><tr><td>8172745</td></table>"
        Dim testArr As String() = Regex.Split(testSource, "<tr>")

        'Show The Array in TextBox1
        TextBox1.Lines = testArr

    End Sub
End Class
```

All The Best